# advance carousel using ionic 3 and angular 4

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

i am new in hybrid application development and want to make a advance carousel like http://sebelga.github.io/ionic-advanced-carousel/demo/ for ionic 3 application. i tried this link but its not working with ionic 3 or may be i did it wrong.  i want this for taking user selection. is there any library for this? if you have any material like this for ionic 3 and angular 4 kindly share the link or code. 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You need to leverage Slides component: https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#slides

Slides component can be configured to have multiple slides visible at a time on the screen (see documentation). So what you want can be achieved via slides.

If you struggle with it - let me know with what exactly.

Here is a snippet of the "view" where I use variables to define amount of slides I need to show in the view:

```
<ion-slides "bottomPanelSlides" no-padding lazyLoading [slidesPerView]="slidesPerView">
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let slide of slides; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i" (click)="processItem($event, i); storylineAdd();">
        <img [hidden]="sliderLoading" (load)="revealSlides();" src="./assets/img/filtersubject.png" [attr.data-index]="i"/>
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

In my example I show small images in a horizontal listview fashion. But you could do text for sure.